# App loader hangs when publishing to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I cannot upload my app to the App Store. It hangs on 'verifying assets'. My app validates and I don't get any errors, my bundle id's are also matching. I have attached some screenshots.

How can I upload my app?

Comment: Give a try with Application loader from Xcode Developer tools

Comment: Is that the command tools? I can't find any developer tools on the developer website.

Comment: @Bomber, Be care, you should hide your application private details like `bundle identifier`, `signing certificate`, `Apple ID`, `SKU`, etc. when you post anything from Xcode publicly.

Comment: @Bomber Xcode -> Open Developer Tools -> Application loader